# How to preserve Rails' number formatting after jQuery has done calculations on it?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an **Invoice** with a number of **Items**. When a user decides to change the **price** or the **quantity** of an Item, the **subtotal** of that item gets instantly updated through these two jQuery functions:

```
// Re-calculate item subtotal when quantity gets changed
$('[id$=quantity]').change(function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
  var price = $(this).closest('.item_fields').find('[id$=price]').val();
  recalculate_subtotal($(this), price, quantity);       
});

function recalculate_subtotal($element, price, quantity) {
  $element.closest('.item_fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity);     
}
```

This works fine. However, it seems that jQuery cannot preserve the formatting of the subtotal field. This is what it looks like in my code:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'Subtotal', number_to_currency(f.object.subtotal), :disabled => true %>
```

So when a user creates a new item, the subtotal is formatted correctly by Rails, e.g. like so: `$200.00`

But the moment he changes an item's price or quantity, all formatting disappears and only the naked integer remains, e.g. `200`.

Is there a way to preserve Rails' formatting using jQuery?

What makes matters even more complicated is that in my case the formatting is derived from a .yml file, so it should be able to adapt to a different format in the long run, if the user wishes so.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Once you call JQuery, you are using JavaScript, and JavaScript formats differently, like using toPrecision(2).

Rails has moved away from ruby or ruby on rails centered solutions like rjs and observers.

Yours is a good example of a counter argument that ruby on rails centered solutions fit in with RoR development, and use the same skill set without needing to train/hire people with a *different* skill set.  Your example is that keeping things RoR allows you to centralize the formatting, or localization, or user preferences.

So the only way to centralize the formatting using common parameters is to write or find JavaScript which works like some ruby formatting.  Then you can send the formatting parameter from the yaml expanded in the page as a parameter to the JavaScript formatting.

*Edit further explanation in response to comment*

This is a case for erb in a JavaScript file.  Use a .js.erb extension for the file which defines recalculate_subtotal.  Write a helper method get_format in ruby, and use this code in your .js.erb file:

```
function format_number(value, <%= get_format %>)
{
    ...
}

function recalculate_subtotal($element, price, quantity)
{
  format_number($element.closest('.item_fields').find('#Subtotal').val(price * quantity));
}
```

For me, that's the easy part.  Writing the contents of format_number is hard. :)

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for your help! Looks like I will have to pass the formatting parameters from the Yaml file into jQuery somehow. I have yet to find a way to do that, though.